# opencv: camera calibration image not being displayed

Tags: python, opencv

So I took a bunch of pictures with my camera and have followed the tutorial posted here: http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_calibration/py_calibration.html

but I've ran into a problem. I'm getting an empty image from the drawchessboardcorners function and I'm not exactly sure why. Note I am new to opencv and so this may be trivial for some but right now I can't figure it out. I'm using opencv 2.4.10.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# termination criteria
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)

# prepare object points, like (0,0,0), (1,0,0), (2,0,0) ....,(6,5,0)
objp = np.zeros((6*7,3), np.float32)
objp[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:7,0:6].T.reshape(-1,2)

# Arrays to store object points and image points from all the images.
objpoints = [] # 3d point in real world space
imgpoints = [] # 2d points in image plane.

for i in range (1,13):
    img = cv2.imread('calibrate/calibrate' + str(i) + '.jpg')
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Find the chess board corners
    ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, (9,6),None)

    # If found, add object points, image points (after refining them)
    if ret == True:
        objpoints.append(objp)

        corners2 = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray,corners,(11,11),(-1,-1),criteria)
        imgpoints.append(corners)

        # Draw and display the corners
        img = cv2.drawChessboardCorners(img, (9,6), corners2,ret)
        cv2.imshow('img',img)
        cv2.waitKey(500)
    else:
        print "No Calibration"

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Here's a picture taken by my webcam:
[image]

Here's a picture of the error code:
[image]

I modified the code a bit to work with the pictures that I took (using a program I wrote). For example, the for loop is there simply because I have 12 photos with names like calibrate1,calibrate2 and so forth. I'm pretty stumped on this one, and hopefully one of you can give me insight! Thanks

Comment: opencv version ? the tutrorials are for 3.0, 2.4 differs.your image is empty. try `cv2.drawChessboardCorners(img, (9,6), corners2,ret)` (with out using the returned image)

Comment: The error says that you are passing an empty image to `imshow`. Maybe you should check that your image is correctly loaded ?

Comment: @berak when i make that edit, the photos are displayed but no corner detection is shown on the images. It does get rid of the error code however

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after @berak's comment I decided to uninstall opencv 2.4 and install opencv 3.0 and behold, the above code worked! Thank you @berak